# Fresh Install - WP6 - Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page

Tags: wp-admin

I was able to use the

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
```

$_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';

commands to get around the too many redirects error.

Now, I can see the site, however, when attempting to log-in, once it gets past the log-in screen, it tells me: Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.

If I go back to the site itself, the admin bar populates at the top of the browser.

The links within that bar all go to 404 pages.

Domain purchased through CloudFlare
Hosted at GoDaddy (inside my MediaTemple account)
cPanel Location Main Config file - does not seem to exist in file management, or when trying to browse to it.

What am I doing wrong with this Installatron install?

Comment: What's "Installatron"? You'll need to talk to your hosting support team.